# URL forwarding to index page

Tags: php, html

Okay so when users type in www.shareit.me/matt i want it to take them to www.shareit.me/index.html How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `.htaccess` file I commonly use.  I have it forward to `index.php`, but changed it to `.html` and it should work the same.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.html
RewriteRule . index.html
```

Comment: where do I save an .htaccess file?

Comment: in your base directory, you wwwroot/.  Just open up notepad, copy and paste, save it as .htaccess and upload it.

Comment: This sends everything except existing files or directories to index.html - not sure OP wanted that. He only wanted to rewrite the matt URI to index.html

Answer (score 1):

This rule in your .htaccess file should be enough:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^matt/?$ index.html [NC,QSA]
```

Place the file in the document root.